# import pylab fails, even after reinstalling matplotlib, libpng, and brew

Tags: python, matplotlib, libpng

Recently upgraded to OSX Sierra (10.12.1), upgraded some packages (don't remember what), and now this is happening (see error message). I tried reinstalling `libpng`, `brew` + `libpng`, successfully linked `libpng`, reinstalled `matplotlib`, and I'm still getting this error.  Any ideas what to try next?

`matplotlib` version: 1.5.3

python version:

```
>>> print (sys.version)
2.7.12 |Anaconda 2.2.0 (x86_64)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:43:17) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)]
```

Full error message:

```
In [1]: import pylab

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-0c66bb86b884> in <module>()
----> 1 import pylab

/Users/lweiss/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylab.py in <module>()
----> 1 from matplotlib.pylab import *
  2 import matplotlib.pylab
  3 __doc__ = matplotlib.pylab.__doc__

/Users/lweiss/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pylab.py in <module>()
229 # make mpl.finance module available for backwards compatability, in case folks
230 # using pylab interface depended on not having to import it
--> 231 import matplotlib.finance
232 
233 from matplotlib.dates import date2num, num2date,\

/Users/lweiss/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/finance.py in <module>()
 25 from matplotlib.dates import date2num
 26 from matplotlib.cbook import iterable, mkdirs
---> 27 from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection, PolyCollection
 28 from matplotlib.colors import colorConverter
 29 from matplotlib.lines import Line2D, TICKLEFT, TICKRIGHT

/Users/lweiss/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py in <module>()
 25 import matplotlib.artist as artist
 26 from matplotlib.artist import allow_rasterization
---> 27 import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases
 28 import matplotlib.path as mpath
 29 from matplotlib import _path

/Users/lweiss/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py in <module>()
 60 
 61 import matplotlib.tight_bbox as tight_bbox
---> 62 import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
 63 from matplotlib.path import Path
 64 from matplotlib.cbook import mplDeprecation, warn_deprecated

/Users/lweiss/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py in <module>()
 16 from matplotlib.ft2font import FT2Font, KERNING_DEFAULT, LOAD_NO_HINTING
 17 from matplotlib.ft2font import LOAD_TARGET_LIGHT
---> 18 from matplotlib.mathtext import MathTextParser
 19 import matplotlib.dviread as dviread
 20 from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties

/Users/lweiss/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py in <module>()
 58 
 59 import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
---> 60 import matplotlib._png as _png
 61 ####################
 62 

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/lweiss/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libpng16.16.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/lweiss/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: _png.so requires version 39.0.0 or later, but libpng16.16.dylib provides version 34.0.0
```

Comment: It looks like you have an old version of libpng, even after reinstalling. Did you do `brew update && brew upgrade libpng`?

Comment: Did you finally fixed this error ? I have exactly the same issue with identical OS, python version and matplotlib, and I've tried all the things you described as well. I'm still getting this error.

Comment: @Léonard you may need to downgrade your version of `libpng` as indicated below.

Comment: @caasjj thanks, I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs on OS X 10.11 also, and upgrading the `libpng` does not fix it.  The version of `matplotlib` I had was 1.5.3.  I had to revert to an older version with:

`pip install matplotlib==1.4`

and that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should try is to upgrade the version of libpng that homebrew installs by:

```
brew update && brew upgrade libpng
```

If that does not work, you should try to *fully* uninstall libpng and then re-install it

```
$ sudo brew uninstall libpng
$ sudo rm '/usr/local/bin/libpng-config'
$ for i in `brew link --overwrite --dry-run libpng`; do sudo rm $i; done
$ sudo brew install libpng
```